# Significance of many-to-many relationships?

Tags: programming-practices, objective-c

How important are to-many relationships in iOS programming? Do you often hold a list of pointers to objects in an array in your codes?

I don't think I fully understand the concept of to-many relationships, let alone how to implement them into code. From my current understanding, to-many relationships holds a list of pointers to one or more class objects and their corresponding properties and instance variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are important when you have to simulate a real-world many-to-many relationship.

Examples of many-to-many relationships:

- [Order details](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/images/ManyToMany.png)
- [Product/Vendor](http://gwb.blob.core.windows.net/claraoscura/6103/o_Many2Many.JPG) relationships
- [Hotel Room](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/media/21629/bookings.png) bookings
- [School Class Registration](http://thedatafarm.com/LearnEntityFramework/files/media/image/WindowsLiveWriter/ManytoManyRelationshipsintheEntityDataMo_852F/m2m2_thumb_1.png)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So from what I understand many-to-many ties two class's together into a third class? So for the example above 'Order details', there are two class' Order and Products, which come together to form a third class OrderDetails? Do all of the properties and instance variables from the class' Order and Products also come into OrderDetails class?

Comment: Not exactly.  It just models the relationship. A relationship can be modeled with ID's between classes, or it can be modeled with ID's in a database table.  It can be modeled with anything that establishes a many-to-many relationship between the "classes."  In a database, you can get a collection of *tuples* by JOINing the tables together.  Each tuple would represent a single record that relates a record in one outside table with the record in the other outside table.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok I think I see where this is going - awesome. So many-to-many practically joins two existing class properties into a third class array. Yes, your above post makes sense to me. I see now. Awesome. It's just hard to implement it to objective-c code. I would upvote if I could, thanks.